# Chart.js add label inside bubble chart

Tags: chart.js

I have a bubble chart that looks like this currently in Chart.js:

[image]

I simply want to add labels to the chart, like this:

[image]

`How can this be done?`

Current code: http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/7323/

Comment: please share your code to debug easily

Comment: Added here http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/7323/

Answer (score 0):

To achieve expected result, use below option

HTML:

```
<section class="content" ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="ChartCtrl">
  <canvas chart-data="data" chart-labels="labels" chart-options="options" chart-series="series" class="chart-bubble" id="base"></canvas>
</section>
<span  id="q1">Quadrant1</span>
<span  id="q2">Quadrant2</span>
<span  id="q3">Quadrant3</span>
<span  id="q4">Quadrant4</span>
```

CSS:

```
#q1{
  position:absolute;
  margin-top:-30%;
  margin-left:80%;
}
#q2 {
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: -30%;
  margin-left: 20%;
}
#q3 {
  position: absolute;
  margin-bottom: -30%;
  margin-left: 20%;
}
#q4 {
  position: absolute;
  margin-bottom: -30%;
  margin-left: 80%;
}
```

Codepen- http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/LkmZkL